# EXCEL Match with 2 worksheets return Column Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I am trying to use 2 worksheets where initially the WK2 Col C data in worksheet 2 is found and set equal to its data in wk1 Col A. The numbers in WK1 Col A will have several duplicates over the 10000 rows in the spreadsheet. No idea if this is correct, but due to the duplicates I've been trying to write an equation in WK1 Col B to say if WK1 Col A cell can be found in WK2 Col C, then return WK2 Col D in WK1 Col B.

I've tried a few different ways with the INDEX, CELL. VLOOKUP equations below but cant get it to work and getting spill returns :(  Not sure what to do

WK1 COL B

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!$D$2:$D$111,MATCH(Sheet1!$A2,'Sheet2'!$C$2:$C$111,0),"")
```

Comment: Your verbiage says columns B and A in Sheet2, but your formula uses D and C.  By the way remove the `,""` from the INDEX and it should work, as long as the columns are correct.  YOu are looking for the match in column C and returning the value in column D.